# How to fetch mp3 metadata in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, id3

I am making a music player app. It is able to read the files but I am not sure how to extract the metadata. I want to be able to fetch the song length and the album image mainly. Though the album image might be a problem I am also happy with other data like the song duration and album name and other stuff.

I would be really helpful if someone could provide me a way. I referred to [id3](https://pub.dev/packages/id3) package but there isnt much written as to how to handle the output. A proper code example would be really helpful. I am a complete beginner in dart.

THANKS WORLD.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611412/local-audio-files-metadata-in-flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question [Local Audio files metadata in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611412/local-audio-files-metadata-in-flutter).

Right now you can use [flute_music_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flute_music_player) package for achieving the said task but it is only available in Android as of now. So my best guess will be for you to write Platform channel for iOS

You can try this package and check if it still works. It's not updated recently [media_metadata_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/media_metadata_plugin)

Comment: Hello. I dont want to go with flute_music_player as there is a problem with it that wont work with the specific feature I am trying to implement. But I dont know if it can. I want to pass the path to the audio to the player instead of the player searching the whole device. But Thanks for the answer <3

Comment: Local Audio files metadata in flutter question is deleted from the stackoverflow. I use file_picker for selecting the files and for playing music i use assets_audio_player  but i don't find a way to fetch the cover image from music file.